# How to enable shared trust in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In our group we have a common Jupyter server running on a machine in the local network. Two or three people write and edit notebooks collaboratively using their individual PCs and browsers.

Now the Jupyter/IPython security model does not trust notebooks written by others unless you explicitly enable trust (therefore re-writing the notebook).

How can my colleagues open a notebook which I authored without re-writing the key in the notebook?

The [manual](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html) provides a tiny hint that one can use

```
c.NotebookApp.secret_file = "/path/to/notebook_secret"
```

to share trust but is short on details how this should work in practice. Where does the `notebook_secret` file be stored, on the common server or on each client PC? Where do add this code, in each notebook or in a common configuration file?

Comment: The manual is, regrettably, out of date. I'll try to fix that. You now need to set `c.NotebookNotary.data_dir` to a filesystem location which will be shared between the users. However, this now stores an SQLite database (of notebook hashes, essentially), and SQLite doesn't work well on NFS. We're trying to work out better ways to do this [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1782).

Comment: @ThomasK Unfortunately this does not work anymore. In my case I set that directory and copied my `notebook_secret` and `nbsignatures.db` there, but they seem to be not used or the files are specific to one machine or something else necessary for that to work does not work. I tried it with a docker container, into which I `COPY`ed my files.